# Azure Websites - monitoring data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

We're trying to understand the intricacies of monitoring data that Windows Azure Management API returns for Azure Websites (not Webroles)

For example, the image below describes a data point retrieved for CPUTime.  It appears to indicate that during the 10:00pm thru 10:39pm range, I've used up 3.171 seconds of CPU.  Is this translatable to CPU utilization (in percentage form) that we're all accustomed to seeing in Perfmon?

Does this get reset every clock hour and what is TimeGrain?

Interestingly, the "Count" indicates "1" - which to me implies the number of measurements in the timeslot, but even after subsequent calls are issued to the API, the Count stays at 1 (however the Total value changes).

Ultimately the goal is to translate the captured metric to standard CPU utilization % that everyone is accustomed in seeing during Perfmon monitoring.

I'm guessing that two relatively close measurements need to be taken, the delta between measurements computed (in milliseconds) and divided by the total span between the measurements (in milliseconds) - in order to produce a percentage value.  Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Web Sites in 'Free' and 'Shared' mode is running in multi-tenant environment. You can't translate CpuTime to CPU utilization % in this case. In case of Reserved mode it is technically possible, but this value is not currently exposed. Please also note, if you upgrade your web site to 'Reserved' mode all other web sites will be also upgraded and share same reserved instances.